# Quickest way to update the amplify express server for REST?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Right now I'm doing the following after updating methods in the express server (Not adding new paths).

```
amplify update api
//answer all the questions
amplify push
```

Is there a faster way to iterate on the express server when we are not changing the paths?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just running `amplify push` is enough, unless a path is being added, removed, or updated.